# SQL injection concatenation vs parameter

Tags: sql-injection

I have been reading an article on sql injection attack and in there, they have been saying that this statement is prone to injection attack:

`"SELECT * from tblBlah where userId" +userId`

but this query is not"

`"SELECT * from tblBlah where userId = @userId";`

i am trying to find an explaination on why that is the case. they both are are expecting a parameter. could it be the first query can accept a parameter from URL and second cannot?

Comment: The second one is likely meant as some form of _prepared statement_.

Comment: I strongly recommend this [reading](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the case of the first query someone could pass the following value for `userId`:

```
 = 3; DELETE FROM tblBlah;
```

This would be string concatenated and would result in the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * from tblBlah where userId= 3; DELETE FROM tblBlah;
```

Of course, this would be catastrophic for your database.

I think in the case of the second query, the database would compile it internally to be a single `SELECT` statement.  The value of the parameter would be inserted where the placeholder is, but only as data.  Even if we tried the following assignment:

```
@userId = '= 3; DELETE FROM tblBlah;';
```

we would end up with the following query:

```
SELECT * from tblBlah where userId = '= 3; DELETE FROM tblBlah;';
```

In other words, we tried to inject code but all we were really able to do was inject a string *parameter*.  This could cause a bad query to fire, but it would not allow a malicious user to call `DELETE`.  In fact, the user would have zero control over which statement executes.

This is a simple example demonstrating the power of prepared statements.  With prepared statements, the general template or structure of the query is already compiled before the query actually runs.  Portions of the statement have parameter placeholders, which however do not alter the query through concatenation, but only by assigning positioned values.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in such detail.

Answer (score 1):

With your first query the database doesn't know if it have more conditions or what's exactly the purpose of the query, then the database will trust the query on a blind way.

On the second one the database at start will get the query and know exactly what you want to do and how many parameters the query should have, if something coming from the parameters changes the initial behavior, or simply is not there, the query it will be not trusted and would throw an error.

I will explain with examples now.

If you do like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE User=' + User + ' AND Pwd=' + Pass
```

Someone can easily inject SQL there, just filling the user with `'' AND 1=1--` because `--` will comment away the second part of the query and the condition will be true, then it will print the table data.

The query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE User='' AND 1=1-- AND Pwd=' + Pass
```

Now lets do it with parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM custTable WHERE User= @user AND Pass=@password

//Someone filled the userfield with SQL injection:
@user = "'' AND 1=1--"
@password = ""
```

Then the query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM custTable WHERE User= '' AND 1=1-- AND Pass=@password
```

The query looks the same but works on a different way, the database will process the query, get the @username parameter and a blank password, then it will should come as false.

I would add it depends how do you use the the SQL parameters and on which language are you programming, it will be more or less safe, but one of the safest ones will be use store procedures with parameterized queries.

Comment: In both cases, the query is "trusted," but in the second case little damage can be done due to the parameter.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are completely right, I was writing down my answer before reading yours.

Comment: Thank you both for explaining.